# OCaml matrix manipulation

Tags: function, matrix, ocaml

I'm looking to write an OCaml function with this structure:
`rows : int list list -> char list -> int list = <fun>`.
I'm having some trouble as I'm fairly new to the language.
The program should take each list and perform an operation like addition or multiplication with it's elements. For example: `rows [[1;2;0];[4;5;6];[1;2;9]] [’+’;’-’;’*’];;-: int list = [3;-7;18]`

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: SO is for concrete questions and direct answers, not a general forum for discussing programming and languages. Also, people here won't do your homework and since you're not the only one person who is asking exactly the same question for the last week - it is the homework. Beware, that teachers are also aware of sites like SO and don't treat cheaters well. But that's again, not to say that you should ask. But please, try something yourself, learn the language by reading the manual and then ask concrete questions. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why won't your list actually have the integer functions(+,-,*,/) in it?

Comment: @G4143 the function is supposed to be passed a list of lists and a list of integers containing the operation signs, then it does the first operation on the first list in the list of lists, the second on the second list and so on.

Comment: What if the list of list is longer than the list of operators?

Comment: @G4143 My intentions were to just end the program with an error message and have the input be repeated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the basic problem? Note: I left important part for you to answer.

```
let nums =
  [
    [1;2;0];
    [4;5;6];
    [1;2;9];
  ]

let ops = ['+'; '-'; '*';]

let rec rows l o =
  match (l, o) with
  | ([],[]) -> []
  | (hd::tl, op::tlo) ->
    (
      match hd with
      | [] -> 0::(rows tl tlo)
      | h::t -> (*The important part goes here*)
    )
  | _ -> failwith "Uneven list"

let ans = rows nums ops
```